# How do you verify that a method was never called on a null object?

Tags: java, mockito

I have an Object that may be null.

I want to verify that when an object is null, it's method is not invoked.

I wrote a test case that looks like this:

```
    String str = mock(String.class);
    str = null;
    verify(str, never()).length();
```

But Mockito replies with:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.String
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
```

How do I verify that my a method is not invoked on a null Object?

Comment: You mean `object reference` is not `null` right?

Comment: On the contrary, I want to verify that *NO* methods are invoked on the nulled Object.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Comment: What for? If a method is called on a null reference you'll get a NullPointerException and the test will fail as well.

Comment: Making sure that you don't write code with null pointer exceptions in it isn't really what Mockito does.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use mock operations on a null object reference.

But if any method is called on your null object reference, then you'll get a NPE - this should fail your test (unless you were expecting a NPE, of course).

You can also use [assertNull()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNull%28java.lang.Object%29) to be sure that `str` is in fact null, if this is part of your test result.